# PG::connectionBad error in logs for Rails 5 heroku app, is mismatched IPs the reason?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku, deployment, ruby-on-rails-5

Heroku deleted my rails 5 app's database. I created a new DB, they recovered the old one and copied it to the new one, then attached it. But my site won't load. Heroku support hasn't tried to help beyond giving links to troubleshooting I've done many times. I've been trying every possible fix I can find for a week.

In the error message, I noticed the host that is listed for my database in the settings does not match the host in the timeout error.

MY HOST (per heroku settings): **ec2-18-2XX-36-213**.compute-1.amazonaws.com

The host in the logs: **ec2-5X-83-25-2X7**.compute-1.amazonaws.com

*(I replaced a couple numbers with X b/c Idk if that's sensitive information)*

Is that why the connection won't work? If so, how do I fix it?

FATAL -- : [465fe0b0-f387-4b4a-b215-779dbb8dbf7e] PG::ConnectionBad (connection to server at "ec2-5X-83-25-2X7.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (5X.83.25.2X7), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out

Comment: How did you try to reconfigure your Heroku app to talk to the new database?

Comment: That was the question I'd been trying to get answered, I figured there must be something that needed updating. So I ran pretty much every command I could find. rake db:migrate, pg:reset, can't even remember everything from the past week. What should I have done??

Comment: I'm asking how you pointed your app to the new database. Is this a new Heroku Postgres database, or one you're managing independently on AWS?

Comment: actually with everything I tried, I ended up erasing the database. Heroku had to once again take the one they deleted last week and restore it to this new database. So to answer your question, I have no idea. That's what I've been trying to figure out how to do by running terminal commands and playing with the config vars. What should I do?? If there's a tutorial please direct me to it.

It's a new heroku postgres database I had to make so heroku could copy the one they deleted to it.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for being the only person who even attempted to help over a week and 2 stack overflow posts. Your questions led me to search for how to make the DB communicate, and I eventually found the answer in a stack overflow comment on a post from 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, all I needed to do was go into my new database's settings, copy the DATABASE_URL, go into the config vars of my app, and paste over the old DATABASE_URL.

So many wasted hours because heroku tech support couldn't articulate that. Took 5 seconds, then site loaded immediately. Didn't need to push anything, commit anything, change any code, etc

Comment: That's probably not the right solution... are you sure the new database is [attached to](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-add-ons#using-the-command-line-interface-attaching-an-add-on-to-another-app) the correct app? Generally, you should let Heroku manage the `DATABASE_URL` itself. This lets it update the connection parameters as part of routine maintenance, for example. If you manually copy a connection string today, there's no guarantee it won't break tomorrow.

Comment: Knowing what and how certain variables were managed was extremely confusing. Didn't help that the database apparently has 4 different names that people use interchangeably to ensure it remains confusing. DATABASE_URL, the actual database url, the heroku_cyan_url (or whatever), the database name that's like parallell-34233-something, the actual database ID that's like 94598a4598 - every tutorial and help section refers to it differently and expects me/us to know wtf they're talking about. TL;DR I have no idea. If heroku manages it, why weren't they? The site loaded the second I made the change

Comment: "If heroku manages it, why weren't they?"—I suspect, because it isn't attached to your app as I suggested in my previous comment. "The site loaded the second I made the change"—and I expect it will fail the second Heroku does routine maintenance on the database.

Comment: heroku tech support said "we have restored the deleted database to the [new DB] that is attached to [my app]." I believe you that it's a temporary fix, though, what is the proper way to do it?